# How to get inserted document inside nested array in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to push a document inside nested array in mongoose. I am also successfull in saving the document in the array. But what I want is that the newly saved document should be returned in the callback function( because it has ObjectId in it which is what I need). Below is my code:

```
SocialPost.updateOne({_id: req.body._id, "comments._id": req.body.commentId},
        {$push :{'comments.$.replies': {replyAuthor: req.body.replyAuthor, reply: req.body.reply, 
            authorProfile: req.body.authorProfile, dateOfReply: req.body.dateOfReply}}},
            function(err,result){
                if(err)
                    res.json({err});
                else
                    {console.log(result);res.json({});}
            })
```

The output on console is below:

```
{
  n: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1624684305 },
    t: 8
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000008,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1624684305 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1624684305 }
}
```

I can't see the newly inserted document in the above output.

My question is how can I retrieve the newly inserted document( or even the repiles array or comment array) so the I can return the document to the user?

Thank You!

*EDIT*:
In case anyone needs it, below is the schema:

```
const PostSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    uid: String,
    email: String,
    title: String,
    userProfile: String,
    description: String,
    file: String,
    fileType: String,
    subGratis: String,
    dateTime: String,
    likes: Number,
    hearts: Number, 
    comments:[
        {
            commentAuthor: String,
            uid: String,
            comment: String,
            userProfile: String,
            dateOfComment: String,
            replies: [{
                replyAuthor: String,
                authorProfile: String,
                reply: String,
                dateOfReply: String
            }]
        }
    ]
},{collection: 'SocialPost'});
```

Comment: `updateOne` doesn't return the updated document - just the update result. If you want the updated document to be seen in the result you need to use the `findOneAndModify` _or_ `findOneAndUpdate` methods. These methods also have a _projection_ option for the returned document.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting desired result now!